# Full six degrees motion tracking with standard iOS/Android devices

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

Project Tango has [Motion Tracking API](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/motion-tracking). I'm curious what's the best way to track a motion in similar way (i.e. track position and orientation of the user's device in full six degrees of freedom) on standard Android and iOS devices using any kind of 3D party SDKs and/or physical additions (like markers or beacons)?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [visual odometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_odometry).

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/motion-tracking#more_about_tracking_rotation_and_acceleration):

> Tango implements Motion Tracking using visual-inertial odometry, or VIO, to estimate where a device is relative to where it started.
>
> Standard visual odometry uses camera images to determine a change in position by looking at the relative position of different features in those images. For example, if you took a photo of a building from far away and then took another photo from closer up, it would be possible to calculate the distance the camera moved based on the change in size and position of the building in the photos.
>
> Visual-inertial odometry supplements visual odometry with inertial motion sensors capable of tracking a device's rotation and acceleration. This allows a Tango device to estimate both its orientation and movement within a 3D space with even greater accuracy. Unlike GPS, Motion Tracking using VIO works indoors.